# R - eliminate duplicate values with while loop

Tags: r, duplicates, time-series

I have a time series dataset, where the initial observations were coming from monthly data. I transformed the date to daily and put each value at the beginning of the month. Now, I would like to add a day to each duplicate value until there are no overlapping dates left in the dataset. This step is crucial for subsequent analysis and plots.

This is to generate a dataset which is similar to mine:

```
sample <- rbind("2007-01-01","2007-02-01","2007-03-01","2007-05-01",
           "2007-06-01","2007-07-01","2007-09-01","2007-10-01",
           "2007-11-01","2007-12-01","2008-01-01","2008-02-01",
           "2008-03-01","2008-05-01","2008-06-01","2008-07-01",
           "2008-09-01","2008-10-01","2008-11-01","2008-12-01",
           "2009-02-01","2009-04-01","2009-05-01","2009-06-01",
           "2009-07-01","2009-09-01","2009-10-01","2009-11-01",
           "2009-12-01","2010-01-01","2010-02-01","2010-03-01",
           "2010-04-01","2010-05-01","2010-05-01","2010-05-01",
           "2010-05-01","2010-05-01","2010-06-01","2010-06-01",
           "2010-06-01","2010-06-01","2010-07-01","2010-07-01",
           "2010-07-01","2010-07-01","2010-07-01","2010-08-01",
           "2010-08-01","2010-08-01","2010-08-01","2010-09-01",
           "2010-09-01","2010-09-01","2010-09-01","2010-09-01",
           "2010-10-01","2010-10-01","2010-10-01","2010-10-01",
           "2010-10-01","2010-11-01","2010-11-01","2010-11-01",
           "2010-11-01","2010-11-01","2010-12-01","2010-12-01",
           "2010-12-01","2010-12-01","2010-12-01","2011-01-01",
           "2011-01-01","2011-01-01","2011-01-01","2011-02-01",
           "2011-02-01","2011-02-01","2011-02-01","2011-03-01",
           "2011-03-01","2011-03-01","2011-03-01","2011-04-01",
           "2011-04-01","2011-04-01","2011-04-01","2011-04-01",
           "2011-05-01","2011-05-01","2011-05-01","2011-05-01",
           "2011-05-01","2011-06-01","2011-06-01","2011-06-01",
           "2011-06-01","2011-06-01","2011-07-01","2011-07-01",
           "2011-07-01","2011-07-01","2011-08-01","2011-08-01",
           "2011-08-01","2011-09-01","2011-09-01","2011-09-01",
           "2011-09-01","2011-10-01","2011-10-01","2011-10-01",
           "2011-10-01","2011-10-01","2011-11-01","2011-11-01",
           "2011-11-01","2011-11-01","2011-11-01","2011-12-01",
           "2011-12-01","2011-12-01","2011-12-01","2011-12-01",
           "2012-01-01","2012-01-01","2012-01-01","2012-01-01",
           "2012-01-01","2012-02-01","2012-02-01","2012-02-01",
           "2012-02-01","2012-02-01","2012-03-01","2012-03-01",
           "2012-03-01","2012-03-01","2012-03-01","2012-04-01",
           "2012-04-01","2012-04-01","2012-04-01","2012-05-01",
           "2012-05-01","2012-05-01","2012-05-01","2012-05-01",
           "2012-06-01","2012-06-01","2012-06-01","2012-06-01",
           "2012-06-01","2012-07-01","2012-07-01","2012-07-01",
           "2012-07-01","2012-07-01","2012-08-01","2012-08-01",
           "2012-08-01","2012-09-01","2012-09-01","2012-09-01",
           "2012-09-01","2012-09-01","2012-10-01","2012-10-01",
           "2012-10-01","2012-10-01","2012-10-01","2012-11-01",
           "2012-11-01","2012-11-01","2012-11-01","2012-11-01",
           "2012-12-01","2012-12-01","2012-12-01","2013-01-01",
           "2013-01-01","2013-01-01","2013-01-01","2013-01-01",
           "2013-02-01","2013-02-01","2013-02-01","2013-02-01",
           "2013-02-01","2013-03-01","2013-03-01","2013-03-01",
           "2013-03-01","2013-03-01","2013-04-01","2013-04-01",
           "2013-04-01","2013-04-01","2013-04-01","2013-05-01",
           "2013-05-01","2013-05-01","2013-05-01","2013-05-01",
           "2013-06-01","2013-06-01","2013-06-01","2013-06-01",
           "2013-07-01","2013-07-01","2013-07-01","2013-07-01",
           "2013-08-01","2013-08-01","2013-08-01","2013-09-01",
           "2013-09-01","2013-09-01","2013-09-01","2013-09-01",
           "2013-10-01","2013-10-01","2013-10-01","2013-10-01",
           "2013-10-01","2013-11-01","2013-11-01","2013-11-01",
           "2013-11-01","2013-11-01","2013-12-01","2013-12-01",
           "2013-12-01","2013-12-01","2013-12-01","2014-01-01",
           "2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01",
           "2014-02-01","2014-02-01","2014-02-01","2014-02-01",
           "2014-02-01","2014-03-01","2014-03-01","2014-03-01",
           "2014-03-01","2014-03-01","2014-05-01","2014-05-01",
           "2014-05-01","2014-05-01","2014-05-01","2014-06-01",
           "2014-06-01","2014-06-01","2014-07-01","2014-07-01",
           "2014-07-01","2014-07-01","2014-08-01","2014-08-01",
           "2014-09-01","2014-09-01","2014-09-01","2014-09-01",
           "2014-09-01","2014-10-01","2014-10-01","2014-10-01",
           "2014-10-01","2014-11-01","2014-11-01","2014-11-01",
           "2014-11-01","2014-12-01","2014-12-01","2014-12-01",
           "2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01",
           "2015-02-01","2015-02-01","2015-02-01","2015-02-01",
           "2015-03-01","2015-03-01","2015-03-01","2015-03-01",
           "2015-04-01","2015-04-01","2015-04-01","2015-04-01",
           "2015-05-01","2015-05-01","2015-06-01","2015-06-01",
           "2015-06-01","2015-07-01","2015-07-01","2015-08-01",
           "2015-08-01","2015-09-01","2015-09-01","2015-09-01",
           "2015-10-01","2015-10-01","2015-11-01","2015-11-01",
           "2015-12-01","2016-01-01","2016-01-01","2016-01-01",
           "2016-01-01","2016-02-01","2016-02-01","2016-02-01",
           "2016-02-01","2016-03-01","2016-04-01","2016-04-01",
           "2016-04-01","2016-04-01","2016-05-01","2016-05-01",
           "2016-06-01","2016-06-01","2016-06-01","2016-06-01",
           "2016-07-01","2016-07-01","2016-07-01","2016-07-01",
           "2016-08-01","2016-08-01","2016-08-01","2016-08-01",
           "2016-08-01","2016-08-01","2016-08-01","2016-08-01",
           "2016-08-01","2016-08-01","2016-09-01","2016-09-01",
           "2016-09-01","2016-09-01","2016-10-01","2016-10-01",
           "2016-10-01","2016-11-01","2016-11-01")
sample <- as.data.frame(sample)
sample$Value <- (1:355)
colnames(sample)[1] <- c("Date")
View(sample)
```

After reading up on this a bit, I came to the conclusion that what I need to do is a while loop which runs through the date column and adds one day to each value if it's a duplicate. With the use of the `lubridate package` I do something like this:

```
library(lubridate)    
while(sample$Date==sample$Date[-1]) {sample$Date <- sample$Date+days(1); print(sample$Date);}
```

However, the loop does not run and generates a lot of warnings. Do you have any idea how to solve this? I assume this is a pretty simple question, I am just new to looping.

Thank you!

Comment: share a smaller data and also the expected output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this with `data.table`. First, we'll set things up, including converting the dates from `factor` class:

```
library( data.table )
setDT( sample )
sample[ , Date := as.Date( Date ) ]
```

Then we'll perform your conversion:

```
sample[ , Date := Date + ( seq_len( .N ) - 1L ), by = Date ]
```

What we're doing here is separating out each subset of matching date values, and adding a sequence vector to them. For example, a subset with 4 matching date values will add c(0,1,2,3) days to that Date vector, such that the first value remains the same, and subsequent values are incremented in the manner you describe.

Comment: thank you for this! I was wondering, how would I do it in a way to not only add one day, but distribute the overlapping values throughout the month, to equal distances from each other?

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark as accepted if it answered your question... For an evenly spaced sequence, you'll likely want `seq.Date`. If you need help with `seq.Date`, you can ask in a new question.